# How to add a Keyword before the YouTube Video Title?

Tags: video, youtube, addition, title, keyword

I have a YouTube Module that scrape videos from some YouTube users account daily.
  I want to know, how to I add an extra Keyword before the YouTube Video Title?
  
  Original Title: Matt Mahher - Amazing
  
  I want to change the Title to: New Song - Matt Mahher - Amazing
  
  I want to add Keyword (New Song) before the YouTube Title.
  
  **This is the scripts module I'm using to get YouTube videos in to my website.**

$thepublic = intval($_REQUEST['public']);

$theallowcomments = intval($_REQUEST[allowcomments]);

$theallowratings = intval($_REQUEST[allowratings]);

$theallowembeds = intval($_REQUEST[allowembeds]);

$theallowdownloads = intval($_REQUEST[allowdownloads]);

$themature = intval($_REQUEST[mature]);
  
  $youtube_details = getVideoDetails($youtube_video_id);

$ytitle = $youtube_details['title'];

$ydesc  = $youtube_details['desc'];

$ykeywords  = str_replace(',', ' ', $youtube_details['keywords']);

$yurl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$youtube_video_id;

$yviews  = $youtube_details['views'];

$author  = $youtube_details['author'];

$duration = $youtube_details['duration'];
  
  $approve_videos = $config[approve_videos];
  
  
  ---------------------------------
  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I haven't understood correctly what you mean to do, but I'd do this way:

```
$ytitle = 'New song '.$youtube_details['title'];
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Aptivus, Yes something like that, I'm going test it now. I will reply back how it go. Thanks.

Comment: Aptivus,

What about this one?: $title=$val[title].'';

Comment: yes, you can concatenate whatever you want with the "."
If you find useful my answer, please mark it. Thanks